# ExportToCsv is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, csv, export

I'm working to a project for exporting csv file using this **export-to-csv** library but it returns an error "ExportToCsv is not a constructor" . I'm not sure what might be the problem. Hoping you could help me.

```
 const ExportToCsv  = require('export-to-csv');
 module.exports.ExportToCsv = async (req, res) => {
  try {
   var data = [
   {
   name: 'Test 1',
   age: 13,
   average: 8.2,
   approved: true,
   description: "using 'Content here, content here' "
   },
   {
   name: 'Test 2',
   age: 11,
   average: 8.2,
   approved: true,
   description: "using 'Content here, content here' "
   },
   {
   name: 'Test 4',
   age: 10,
   average: 8.2,
   approved: true,
   description: "using 'Content here, content here' "
   },
 ];

  const options = { 
   fieldSeparator: ',',
   quoteStrings: '"',
   decimalSeparator: '.',
   showLabels: true, 
   showTitle: true,
   title: 'My Awesome CSV',
   useTextFile: false,
   useBom: true,
   useKeysAsHeaders: true,
  };

  const csvExporter = new ExportToCsv(options);

  csvExporter.generateCsv(data);

  }catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use either of these statements for importing the module:

`const ExportToCsv  = require('export-to-csv').ExportToCsv`

`import { ExportToCsv } from 'export-to-csv';`

The problem with your code is that you're importing and referring to the entire module, what you need is a specific function in the module. The error correctly points out that your variable `ExportToCsv` is not a constructor, which is true as it refers to the entire exports object from the module that you're importing. The constructor function that you need to use is a property on the object that's exported from the module so you have to point to that specific property.

Comment: I tried changing it to "import { ExportToCsv } from 'export-to-csv';" but it returns an error "Cannot use import statement outside a module".

Comment: Did you try the other version with require?

Comment: I can't find it. In their documentation its just import { ExportToCsv } from 'export-to-csv.

Comment: const ExportToCsv  = require('export-to-csv').ExportToCsv